# melting only one level of a Multi Index DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a MultiIndex DataFrame and would like to melt out one of the column levels, I have found a way to do this but it involves a two step process (detailed below). I am wondering if there is a way in which I can use `df.melt()` to achieve the intended result in one step

Here is a simplified example of the `df` I am working with

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np

cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [
        ('A', 'temp_avg'),
        ('A', 'temp_predicted'),
        ('B', 'temp_avg'),
        ('B', 'temp_predicted'),
    ]
)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(4,4),
    columns=cols,
    index=pd.date_range(
        datetime.datetime(2013,1,1),
        datetime.datetime(2013,1,4),
    )
)

df.index.names=['date']
```

My current two-step solution is as follows:

```
df_melt = df.reset_index().melt(
    id_vars=[('date', "")],
    var_name=['location', 'name'],
).rename({('date', ''): 'date'}, axis=1)

df_desired = df_melt.pivot_table(
    index=['date', 'location'],
    columns='name',
    values='value',
)
```

I wish to arrive at `df_desired` by a one-step use of `df.melt(**kwargs)` or another function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df_desired = df.stack(0)
```

With name:

```
df_desired = df.rename_axis(['location', None], axis=1).stack('location')
```

Output:

```
                     temp_avg  temp_predicted
date       location                          
2013-01-01 A         0.018696       -1.135884
           B         0.064724        0.790992
2013-01-02 A        -1.572779       -0.365371
           B        -0.572017        0.742684
2013-01-03 A        -3.018399        1.081398
           B         1.223285       -1.810627
2013-01-04 A        -0.889924       -0.652284
           B        -0.251828        0.098451
```

Comment: this is even better! thanks